# How to pass ajax sucess result to another php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my code below I want display `$("#searchresults").html(data)` this result to other page.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: base_url + 'front/searchresult',
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    alert("test");
    var val = $("#searchresults").html(data);
    window.location.assign("<?php echo base_url()?>front/search/" + val);
  }
});
```

Comment: format your code

Answer (score 0):

what exactly is in the data variable you receive from your post? is it a json object? is it plain text?

if it is html, I think you should consider placing the result in a div on the current page, and hide items you don't want to see after searching

relocating after ajax requests is not the way to go. Is it an option in your case, to use a form and change the action attribute of the form to your new location?

```
<form action="front/search/">
<input type="text" name="data">
</form>
```